# Sorting a list depending on frequency

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of elements:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

And need to sort it by the frequency of elements to get this:

```
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

If several elements have the same frequency, sort them by descending value. Can you find any way to do this. I'm using mentioned method but getting my output as:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

My code:

```py
from collections import Counter 

list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
c = Counter(list)
x = sorted(c.most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])) 
y = [([v] * n) for (v, n) in x]
z = sum(y, [])
print(z)
```

Comment: `x = sorted(c.most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)`

Comment: `sorted(lst, key=lambda k, c=Counter(lst): (c[k], -k))`

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

sorted_list_1 = sorted(L, lambda x: (L.count(x), -x))

c = Counter(L)
sorted_list_2 = sorted(L, lambda x: (c[x], -x))
```